# Create automatic subpage (kind of) for each entry

Tags: templating, comments

I really searched this forum for question like this but i was not able to find the answer.

Im creating news portal website, where I have blog entries with url like this
`/blog/SLUG`

I want for every blog article to also have
`/blog/SLUG/comments`
where I will display some info from entry like title, postDate etc
but instead of regular content a I will display comment form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [custom route](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/routing.html#dynamic-routes) for this. While sections only support one default URL for each entry, you can add additional routes related to entries, either through the backend (*Settings* -> *Routes*) or in your `config/routes.php` file.

Add a route that looks like `blog/{slug}/comments` through the backend (you can also use the [alternative syntax for named parameters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#named-parameters), see [advanced routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules)). Point the route directly to a template, or to a controller that renders the comments template.

Inside the template (or controller), you need to use an entry query to find the entry that is specified as part of the URL:

```twig
{% set entry = craft.entries()
    .section('blog')
    .slug(slug)
    .one()
%}
```

Keep in mind that visitors can enter any slug in the URL that will match the route, so this query may return `null`. In this case, you want to throw a 404 error to return a 404 response and display the appropriate [error page](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/routing.html#error-templates):

```twig
{% if not entry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

After this, you have the entry the page belongs to in the `entry` variable and can display its comments as well as the comment submission form.